# If I am given Emp Id on Text Box for onchange How to get the Struts2 Action Response to Jsp Page

Tags: struts2

How to return the values **struts2** action to **JSP** for corresponding textbox

Comment: Unclear what you asked. The action returns a result, it takes the values from the value stack.

Comment: ajax response for Struts2 action to Jsp

Comment: Your REALLY have to put more effort in asking. Or at least in searching.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear 
I think you are looking for ajax response on change the value in text box.